# Apply a function to all column pairs of two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices with the same columns and rows names:

```
> metilacion[1:5,1:5]
            A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1     A4GALT       AAAS
paciente1   0.2804884 0.5816559 1.1814702 -0.6234276 -0.3997400
paciente2   0.5122471 1.2944264 0.5673766  0.4490407 -0.6045510
paciente3  -0.3116356 1.6085049 0.9970350  0.3379215 -0.4787046
paciente4  -0.7220941 0.8771948 2.1445474 -0.5837802 -0.4848246
paciente5  -0.3369999 1.5885716 0.8185654  0.2374583 -0.5698858
> expresion[1:5,1:5]
           A2BP1         A2M     A2ML1      A4GALT       AAAS
paciente1 -0.9082274 -0.17736185 0.8846485 -0.36059775 -0.5624139
paciente2 -1.7152290  1.62368019 0.3292617  1.35968899 -0.9220157
paciente3 -1.0581859  0.33028098 1.1020073  0.01870851 -0.9669236
paciente4 -0.8389615  1.33754885 0.5122861 -0.14583960 -0.8196533
paciente5 -1.5273835  0.06418637 0.2695209  0.03381359 -0.4461490
```

I want to compute the correlation coefficient between all pair of columns between the two matrices and to generate another object with the correlation values for every column pairs.

For example, the correlation coefficient between the first column would be:

```
> cor(metilacion[,1],expresion[,1])
[1] -0.09351992
```

So, I want to generate an object that contains all the correlation values.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `cor(metilacion,expresion)` According to `?cor`, `"If
     ‘x’ and ‘y’ are matrices then the covariances (or correlations)
     between the columns of ‘x’ and the columns of ‘y’ are computed.`

Comment: If you are only looking for corresponding columns, then `diag(cor(metilacion,expresion))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `cor`

```
 cor(metilacion,expression)
 #          A2BP1         A2M      A2ML1     A4GALT        AAAS
 #A2BP1  -0.4887051  0.03682951 -0.0404260  0.5795882 -0.03534625
 #A2M    -0.5909642  0.01572799 -0.1469085  0.3503903 -0.19412101
 #A2ML1   0.8006633  0.17242226  0.1294179 -0.5827062 -0.05502329
 #A4GALT -0.8036390  0.18066923 -0.2026173  0.6824085 -0.32097886
 #AAAS    0.9033514 -0.54378874  0.7694163 -0.7995712  0.13676285
```

If you need to get the `cor` of corresponding columns

```
 diag(cor(metilacion,expresion))
```

Or

```
 mapply(cor, as.data.frame(metilacion), as.data.frame(expresion))
 #    A2BP1         A2M       A2ML1      A4GALT        AAAS 
 #-0.48870510  0.01572799  0.12941787  0.68240850  0.13676285
```